# Using recursion to create a JSON string (replicate stringify)

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, javascript-objects

I'm trying to replicate JSON.stringify() using recursion. I'm a bit confused as to why I'm getting undefined in my returned JSON string. Here's what I've done so far:

```js
var testobj = {num:123,str:"This is a string",bool:true,o:{x:1,y:2},iamnull:null}
var count = 0
var stringifyJSON = function(obj) {

  // your code goes here
  if(obj === undefined){ 
   return console.log("obj was undefined");
  }
  count = count + 1
  if(count > 20){  //I put this here mostly to stop infinite loops assuming this function wouldn't occur over 20 times.
   return console.log("failed")
  }  
  var endarray = [];
if(obj !== undefined && typeof(obj)==='object'){  //If the object isn't undefined and the object is an object...

  for(var prop in obj){
    console.log('"' + prop + '"');
   endarray.push(stringifyJSON(prop) +'"' + ':' +'"'+ stringifyJSON(obj[prop])) //push the items into the array, using recursion. 
  }
  if(typeof(obj) !== undefined){
   return '{' + endarray.join() + '}'
  }
}

  
  
};

//end result is "{undefined":"undefined,undefined":"undefined,undefined":"undefined,undefined":"{undefined":"undefined,undefined":"undefined},undefined":"{}}"

//JSON values cannot be a function, a date, or undefined
```

Could someone indicate where I'm going wrong? With recursion I'm having a problem identifying the source of the issue.

Comment: With recursion you are trying to accumulate a result of some sort. In this case `endarray`. But you are resetting it to an empty array in each iteration of your recursion. You need to declare `endarray` outside the recursive function and build up your results until you complete.

Comment: `typeof(obj) !== undefined` This will always be `true`. Don't use `typeof` to check for `undefined`. It's a shortsighted and unnecessary hack that only causes problems.

Comment: You can define `stringifyJSON` to accept two parameters, check if `endarray` is defined, if yes, push values to the array, else create `endarray`. Though, note, native `JSON.stringify()` implementation can accept more than only an object or array as parameter.

Comment: If you do use typeof it'll need to be compared to a string. Rewritten: `typeof obj !== 'undefined'`

Comment: Also, this is more verbose than needed: `obj !== undefined && typeof(obj)==='object'`. If `typeof obj` is `"object"`, then you already know it's not `undefined`. Maybe you were trying to avoid `null` instead.

Comment: ...and you're not handling primitive types or arrays.

Comment: In response to rasmeister, one of the issues i've been having was that anywhere inside the stringifyJSON function would delete/overwrite the array once i did the recursion, so i didn't know where to put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things needed to get to the correct solution.

First, you don't have a base case for your recursion, so at the base level of each recursive trace, nothing is returned (i.e., undefined is implicitly returned). So first you must add a base case where ints, strings, booleans, and other primitive types, are converted to strings.

Second, you must also check that `obj !== null` before your recursive call, because `typeof(null)` evaluates to "object", strangely enough.

```
var testobj = {num:123,str:"This is a string",bool:true,o:{x:1,y:2},iamnull:null}
var count = 0
var stringifyJSON = function(obj) {

  // your code goes here
  if(obj === undefined){ 
    return console.log("obj was undefined");
  }
  count = count + 1
  if(count > 20){  //I put this here mostly to stop infinite loops assuming this function wouldn't occur over 20 times.
    return console.log("failed")
  }  
  var endarray = [];
if(obj !== undefined && obj !== null && typeof(obj)==='object'){  //If the object isn't undefined and the object is an object...

  for(var prop in obj){
    console.log('"' + prop + '"');
    endarray.push(stringifyJSON(prop) +'"' + ':' +'"'+ stringifyJSON(obj[prop])) //push the items into the array, using recursion. 
  }
  if(typeof(obj) !== undefined){
    return '{' + endarray.join() + '}'
  }
}
if (obj !== undefined) {return String(obj)}


};
```

Comment: This was so far the closest answer as it returns the testobj thrown in, but the quotes are just in the wrong places in the answer.

Comment: Glad to help. I did notice the quotation issue, but your original question asked about the `undefined`s, so that's what I focused on. Hopefully you're able to figure out the quotes yourself, but if not, feel free to write back for more help. :)

Comment: I wrote a jsfiddle trying the same thing and I think I got it right.
https://jsfiddle.net/Vinilux/b7a4oy9w/59/